# Gmc Denali - good bike on a 200 budget?

Tags: road-bike

Alright, so, please, don't flame me for buying a budget bike. My dad recently passed away, and i've been riding his bike. It was a hybrid mountain/road bike. As it slowly died, and i bent the rear axle (Don't ask me how, i don't ride it hard) i debated buying a new bike. I have a few friends with the Denali, and, while they won't let me try it, it looks to be a good bike. One of them has had it for over a year, prompting me to consider it. Personally, i don't have the money for a big budget bike, and only have around $200 to spend. I also pop on and off curbs, and am wondering if that will be much of a problem. Is it worth buying? Will it stand up to my antics? I only weigh 155 Lbs and am a fan of speed. I'm 5'8" but am looking to buy the one intended for much larger people (6'2"-6'5") as i am used to that on my dad's bike. (Plus, i'm only 16, i might get a little bit taller). Biking is pretty much my life, I do it daily. But my old bike is not a road bike, it was a hybrid and is 40 lbs. Is it worth the upgrade? I'd like to get a higher cruising speed as well as a higher top speed. I'd also like to be able to jump on and off curbs if need be. (I've been hit on my bike riding on the road a few times)

Comment: The GMC Denali is a BSO - a bike shaped object. You're better off spending 200 dollars on a used bike. Note that you can probably fix up the old bike for significantly less than 200 dollars.

Comment: I realize that, but it's geared low and has very wide tires - not to mention the weight  http://m.academy.com/shop/pdp/schwinn-men-s-suburban-cs-26-21-speed-comfort-bicycle/pid-534561?deviceType=true

Comment: You're might be pedaling too slow. In any case, voting to close as product rec, but one thing to note is that the Denali might actually even be downright dangerous ontop of being a BSO, given that the handle bars on a lot of them are sawed in half in order to put the grip shifts on. Used is the way to go for road bikes unless you're spending over 500 dollars.

Comment: If your friends have the tools, axles are $20 for the part, $5 for the bearings, $10 for the lube, and $6 for the beer (either for you or for bribe) plus an hour or two in an afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

"As it slowly died, and i bent the rear axle (Don't ask me how, i don't ride it hard) i debated buying a new bike"

Hmmm… If the bent axle is the only major problem the bike has (by "it slowly died" I take you to mean that it was developing other less-serious problems too), if I were you I would do an overhaul and continue with the hybrid.

I don't know if you have the knowledge/experience it would take to do such an overhaul, but if you were willing to put up $200 in quality components and elbow grease, you could probably turn your hybrid into something that's significantly better than any new $200 bike.

If you decide to purchase a bicycle, definitely buy used. Don't get the Denali. A used $200 road bike will last longer.

Answer (score -2):

A $200 bike is not good for someone that rides gentle and you want to ride it a little more than gentle.

Look used as you will find better values.

Go for a bike that is maybe a bit big for you but at 5'8" don't jump to a bike for 6'2".

Then there is style of bike.

- If you want to go fast and bang (jump curbs) then a road bike with
  some solid wheels, axle, frame, ...  That is not is not a $200 bike. 
  Road wheels that will bang are more like $400 alone.
- Consider not going fast and getting like a single speed street or bmx bike.  You are going to need to get up into more the $400+ range but can get a pretty ballistic bike.
- Kind of between is a cyclocross that is like a rugged road bike.  But you not going to get a good one for $200.  You do find some nice used for like $600+ especially at the end of the racing season (Feb).

Comment: The question is about a $200 bike to ride on the road and you suggest a $400 BMX? Buh?